# Undefined array key slug

Tags: arrays, wordpress, themes, undefined, slug

This is the error that shows up on the header area:
: Undefined array key "slug" in on line : Undefined array key "slug" in on line : Undefined array key "slug" in on line
Warning/home/customer/www/awakenthegreatness includes/class-wp-theme-json.php1440

If anyone can help me
Understand why this is happening?
What can I do to fix this?

I am using the Zox News theme on Wordpress

Thanks,

I have been having some issues on my site. It seems to have started since I took the Wordpress php version to 8+

Also my site had a malware redirect attack a few weeks ago

So I had to delete some plugins and go into the server and delete some files there too

I don’t think I deleted any important files

Comment: I have went into the site ground file manager and I do not see any issues with the code the warning is referring to - seems normal to me

Answer (score 0):

In PHP 7, underfined array keys created E_NOTICE. In PHP 8 it is E_WARNING. It's hard to investigate it more without code of the theme but maybe it can be case where your theme is not handling something perfect, however, it went to production because it wasn't throwing any error/warning.

It is just warning. You can hide it in `wp-config.php` file by looking for line

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

and changing it to

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

If the warning will be still visible, you can force it by replacing this line with

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try that once I get back to my computer and will update the thread.

Comment: This is what it already says in the wp-config.php file, I did not have to change it to false

define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

Comment: I added this to the wp-config file, If the warning will be still visible, you can force it by replacing this line with ini_set('display_errors','Off'); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ); define('WP_DEBUG', false); define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false); I will give it one day and see if the problem still persists

Comment: That did not work